# Динамические псевдо-ссылки.

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Любопытную штуку заметил (давно, конечно, заметил), а сейчас было бы очень кстати в моем проекте. Суть вопроса вот в чем: Хороший пример - `vkontakte.ru`. Например, ссылка на страницу человека создается следующим образом: `http://vk.com` и `id` персонажа. Т.е. в работе выглядит так: `http://vk.com/id3864364` Суть вопроса: Каким образом сервер отлавливает GET параметр "id3864364"? Ведь не думаю, что для каждого аккаутна создается своя html (php) страница. :)

Если взять самый простой WEB сервер и выполнить запрос, например, http://localhost/id12345, сервер ругнется на то, что страницы id12345 нет.

Answer (score 3):

В простых случаев подобного результата можно добиться путем использования модуля `mod_rewrite` в сервере `apache`. *Разумеется, что для других `http` серверов эта функциональность тоже поддерживается, однако, `mod_rewrite` - это что-то вроде "примера из учебников".*

Смысл этого модуля *(если совсем по-простому)* - в том, чтобы перенаправлять запросы вида `http://vk.com/id3864364` на, допустим, некоторый скрипт `http://vk.com/generator.php?id=id3864364` по вполне определенным правилам `(rewrite rules).`

*Таким образом, пользователю, запросившему страницу **`http://vk.com/id3864364`,** отдается результат **`http://vk.com/generator.php?id=id3864364`.***

---

Разумеется, мощность `mod_rewrite` не заканчивается на таких тривиальных примеров, однако  это уже тема для самостоятельного изучения.

*Благо материалов и примеров по теме [предостаточно.](http://www.google.ru/?q=mod_rewrite)*

Comment: Небольшая поправка. Может всё же http://vk.com/generator.php?id=3864364 ?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что я использую nginx для проксирования запросов на Apache.

C nginx-ом такие штуки не катят.
Пришлось в конфиге хоста на nginx-е обходиться регулярными выражениями. А именно:

```
      location ~/id(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass                      http://10.1.1.4:8021/myhobby/index.php?id=$1;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass                      http://10.1.1.4:8021/myhobby/;
    }
```

Т.е. запросы вида http://mysite.by/id123 проксиуются на index.php с GET параметром ID, в данном случае, как http://mysite.by/index.php?id=123
Может кому-нибудь и понадобится :))) Мног видел форумов, но ответа на этот вопрос толком не нашел нигде.

Comment: Ты вообще странный тип. Сам спрашиваешь - сам отвечаешь. Если тебе скучно - заведи блог

Comment: Если у вас nginx, то более правильный конфиг будет:

    rewrite ^id(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 last;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.1.1.4:8021/myhobby/;
    }